# How to use focus on image css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, focus

**I am using following code,**

```
<style>
#img1 {width: 300px;}
#img1:focus {border: 2px solid green;}
</style>
<img id="img1" src="test.jpg"/>
```

**But, on clicking image - focus is not working. Image remains same. Green border is not appearing why ?**

Comment: did you mean `#img1:focus` ? (not that that will help though)

Comment: yes yes #img1:focus i have edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An image is not natively focusable.
You can add the attribute `tabindex` to make it focusable (and change `#img:focus ...` to `#img1:focus ...`, as pointed out by Jaromanda X):

```html
<style>
    #img1 {width: 300px;}
    #img1:focus {border: 2px solid green;}
</style>
<img id="img1" src="test.jpg" tabindex="0" />
```